# Solution to Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, boolean-operations

I have a function where I'm calculating two float values with a conditional *if* statement for the return values shown below:

```
 # The function inputs are 2 lists of floats
 def math(list1,list2):
  value1=math(...)
  value2=more_math(...)
  z=value2-value1
  if np.any(z>0):
     return value1
  elif z<0:
     return value2
```

Initially, I ran into the title error. I have tried using np.any() and np.all() as suggested by the error and questions here with no luck. I am looking for a method to explicitly analyze each element of the boolean array (e.g. [True,False] for list w/ 2 elements) generated from the if statement **if z>0**, if it is even possible. If I use **np.any()**, it is consistently returning value1 when that is not the case for the input lists. My problem is similar to [The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502052/the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous-use-a-any) but it went unanswered.

Comment: Could you please edit in a stack trace into your question?

Comment: If `z` is an array, what do you mean by `z>0` ? All the elements in `z` to be greater than zero or at least a one element in `z` to be greater than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]) #for simplicity
b = np.array([0,0,5,5])
c = b.copy() 
condition = a>b  #returns an array with True and False, same shape as a
c[condition] = a[condition] #copy the values of a into c
```

Numpy arrays can be indexed by `True` and `False`, which also allows to overwirte the values saved in these indeces.

Note: `b.copy()` is important, because other wise your entries in `b`will change as well. (best is you try it once without the `copy()` and then have a look at what happens at `b`

Answer (score 0):

If `z` is an array

```
  z=value2-value1
  if np.any(z>0):
     return value1
  elif z<0:
     return value2
```

`z>0` and `z<0` will be boolean arrays.  `np.any(z>0)` reduces that array to one True/False value, which works in the `if` statement.  But the `z<0` is still multivalued, and with give `elif` a headache.